# Create AWS Lambda function to get Users from IAM

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I want to get user details from AWS IAM so I have created a lambda function but there is an error with response code 502. My code is as below.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var iam = new AWS.IAM();
AWS.config.loadFromPath('./config.json');

let getUsers = async (event, callback) => {
    var params = {
        UserName: "5dc6f49d50498e2907f8ee69"
    };

    iam.getUser(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            callback(err)
        } else {
            console.log(data)
            callback(data)
        }
    })
};
```

Comment: Remove the word `async` from your function

Comment: Not working @dev_junwen

Comment: Lambda function receives callback `(event, context, callback)`, try removing the word `async` from your code and update your `(event, callback)` to `(event, context, callback)`

Comment: Still not working. Can you change the code and reply with new code? @dev_junwen

Comment: @dev_junwen it is certainly possible to use Lambda functions with `async`. Both `context` and `callback` objects are *completely* optional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your function already is `async` you don't need to use the old, outdated `callback` approach.

The AWS SDK methods provide a `.promise()` method which you can append to every AWS asynchronous call and, with `async`, you can simply `await` on a Promise.

```js
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    var iam = new AWS.IAM();
    AWS.config.loadFromPath('./config.json');

    let getUsers = async event => {
        var params = {
            UserName: "5dc6f49d50498e2907f8ee69"
        };

        const user = await iam.getUser(params).promise()
        console.log(user)
    };
```

Hopefully you have a handler that invokes this code, otherwise this is not going to work.
If you want to export `getUsers` as your handler function, make sure export it through `module.exports` first. I.e: `module.exports.getUsers = async event...`. Double check that your Lambda handler is properly configured on the function itself, where `index.getUsers` would stand for `index` being the filename (`index.js`) and `getUsers` your exported function.